# how to load java file mainactivity.java file from html file

Tags: android, cordova

Hi guys i am developing an android app in which i want to load the mainactivity.java file back after clicking a button on the html file , i tried one method as shown in the code below but it either takes me to the html view or the activit_main code depending on the comments which i put onto,i want to have facebook login code on my mainactivity so whenever a user presses a button in the index.html file it should redirect me to the mainactivity and then back to the html.....any ideas how to go about it

this is the sample of my mainactivity

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import org.apache.cordova.*;
import android.view.Menu;

public class MainActivity extends DroidGap {
       @Override
       public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                  super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html"); 
                  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);    
       }
}
```

And this is my interface code

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;

public class ActivityLauncher {
    private Context m_context;

    public ActivityLauncher(Context context) {
        m_context = context;
    }

    public void launchActivity() {
        m_context.startActivity(new Intent((Activity)m_context,
             Activity2.class)); // Here you replace by your activity (ContactUs)
    }
}
```

And finally this is how call my java file from html

```
<body>
    <a href="javascript:Android.launchActivity()">Link</a> 
</body>
```

Comment: no error as such but cannot open MainActivity when i load it from html using the code  <a href="javascript:ActivityLauncher.launchActivity()">Link</a>

Answer (score 0):

You cannot call Java methods directly from your HTML page, you have to use a custom url and intercept it with a [`WebViewClient`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html)

```
<body>
   <a href="custom://launchActivity">Link</a>
</body>
```

In your `WebViewClient` implementation, you have to override the [`shouldOverrideUrlLoading()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#shouldOverrideUrlLoading%28android.webkit.WebView,%20java.lang.String%29) method.

The second argument of this method is an url provided as a String object.
If the url matches the custom one you defined in your page, you can launch the new activity from your `WebViewClient` and **return true**. 
If not, return false so the webview can handle the url as usual.

```
public class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading (WebView view, String url) {
        if ("custom://launchActivity".equals(url)) {
            // TODO Launch your activity
            return true;
        }
        // Let the WebView handle the url
        return false;
    }
}
```

Don't forget to attach the `WebViewClient` to your `WebView` with `WebView.setWebViewClient()`

---

**EDIT**: I see from your code that you are using PhoneGap. This should be made more visible in your question. My answer is for **native** Android developement

Comment: if i try to go as per this code , it is giving me error as 'Webview cannot be resolved or is not a field' even when i have it in my activity_main, how to go about it

Comment: My answer is for **native** development. I didn't realize you were using PhoneGap until I submitted it (I added the PhoneGap tag to your question if you don't mind). I am not sure this can translate to PhoneGap.

Comment: hey anyways thanx.... ur answer is very much appreciated.. now m going as per the native development lets c if can turn the table :)

Answer (score 0):

You are really close, all you miss is a javascript interface:

On your main activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends DroidGap {
   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
              super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
              super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");                  
              ActivityLauncher al = new ActivityLauncher (this);
              appView.addJavascriptInterface(al, "ActivityLauncher"); //Create your interface
   }
}
```

And on your javascript you can use:

```
<body>
    <a href="javascript:ActivityLauncher.launchActivity()">Link</a> 
</body>
```

Comment: but with this code it doesn't guide me to the index.html first

Comment: What do you mean? I just copied and pasted your code. The app should start on the same page(index.html)! And when you hit the link, you'll run launchActivity(), starting your Activity2!

Comment: sorry for the delay.....but generally when i run then above code i always used to put comment before //setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); and as soon as i remove that comment it guides me to the activity_main and not to the index.html, what do i do now. I tried to load the MainActivity from Activity2 to and after running the project and after clicking on the button it directly jumps out of the application without any warning or error

Comment: Don't use setContentView. I missed removing that from your code. Phonegap already defines it's own layout. The main point of my reply is the last two lines adding the javascriptInterface. That creates a "bridge" between your javascript and your java code!